# COGNOS 11 - Manual Input Column for Query Calculation

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I am trying to add a column to a ***list*** in COGNOS 11 where one can manually enter data needed for a query calculation. 
So the first column would be data pulled from DB based on query/filter, I want to add a column beside that to enter a value. Next, the column to the right would be a query calculation that is performed on the 2 columns.

> Sample:
> [Column 1][Column 2][Column 3]
> [Data pulled from DB] [Manual Input] [Query Calculation]

I have looked through the user guide, but unable to find any indication on how to do this. I have tried implemented text prompt but I get an error as well. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a parameter.  Add a textbox prompt control to the report page, allowing the user to enter a value and then click a `Finish` button.  You can present the value in every row of column 2 using a query expression

`?myparam?`

or not present the value and simply perform the calculation for column 3.

If I misunderstand and you want the user to enter an arbitrary value on each row, that's Excel, not Cognos.